# regular expression for allowing digit and percentage sign only

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am using this expression for allowing a textbox have only absolute value or percentage only.

```
 ^(-?\d+|\d+[.]\d+)%?$
```

It works fine but it allows to add any other character to be added after digit or % sign.

valid patterns are
-130 
300% 
23.23%

it works fine for $130 as it is invalid
but it treat 130$ as valid.
so, post digit it is allowing any character.

All, I want my textbox to have either absolute value( + or -) or a percentage.

No other character.

Comment: Your regex matches neither `130$` nor `$130`! What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You can try it out at https://regex101.com/. I just did and got expected behaviour. You must be using the regex in a wrong way, please add some c# code to show the problem.

Comment: Problem is this I want only a textbox which can have absolute value(postivive and negative or percetage.

Comment: Also, note that your regex won't match negative decimal numbers such as `-23.23`. You can use something like [`^(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%?$`](https://regex101.com/r/2lUGsC/1) instead.

Comment: @It seems to be working now with the same expression. I don't know what was missing that point of time.

Answer (score 2):

The following regular expression :

```
^[%$][-+]?\d+([,.]\d{1,2})?|^[-+]?\d+([,.]\d{1,2})?[$%]
```

Should work for all this kind of inputs:

- -130300%
- +130300%
- 130300%
- 23.23%
- -23.23%
- +23.23%
- 130$

As you may know, we have two proposition **^[%$][-+]?\d+([,.]\d{1,2})?**  Or (We refer to it by **|** ) and the second part which is **^[-+]?\d+([,.]\d{1,2})?[$%]**

Here is the dissection of the two parts :

1. The first part :

   - **[%$]** The matching string starts by either **$** or **%**
   - **[-+]?** this means that one of the special characters (% or $) can be followed by either **-** or **+** but not necessary.
   - **\d+** this means that is followed by one or more digits.
   - **([,.]\d{1,2})?** this means that is followed by a **(comma ,)** or a **(dot .)** followed by one or two digits **{1,2}** but that is not necessary as this whole expression is followed by **the intoregation mark ?**
2. The second part **^[-+]?\d+([,.]\d{1,2})?[$%]**:

   - **[-+]?** this means that the matching string can start by either **-** or **+** but not necessary.
   - **\d+** this means that is followed by one or more digits.
   - **([,.]\d{1,2})?** this means that is followed by a **(comma ,)** or a **(dot .)** followed by one or two digits **{1,2}** but that is not necessary as this whole expression is followed by **the intoregation mark ?**
   - **[%$]** The matching string should end by either **$** or **%**

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you, For percentage  use `\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?%` for number use `\p{N}`
example https://regex101.com/r/zsNIrG/2

Answer (score -1):

you can use this expression for this : @"[0-9]+%$"